# How to denoise text using T5?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, language-model

I'm trying to denoise text using a T5 model following [the Huggingface doc:](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.28.1/en/model_doc/t5#transformers.T5ForConditionalGeneration)

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("t5-small")

input_ids = tokenizer("The <extra_id_0> walks in <extra_id_1> park", return_tensors="pt").input_ids
labels = tokenizer("<extra_id_0> cute dog <extra_id_1> the <extra_id_2>", return_tensors="pt").input_ids

# the forward function automatically creates the correct decoder_input_ids
loss = model(input_ids=input_ids, labels=labels).loss
loss.item()
```

But I can't figure out how to get the actual text that corresponds to the masked input. They only show how to get the loss and mention

> the forward function automatically creates the correct
> decoder_input_ids

I tried the following:

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("t5-small")

input_ids = tokenizer("The <extra_id_0> walks in <extra_id_1> park", return_tensors="pt").input_ids
labels = tokenizer("<extra_id_0> cute dog <extra_id_1> the <extra_id_2>", return_tensors="pt").input_ids
outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, labels=labels)
loss = outputs.loss
logits = outputs.logits
tokenizer.batch_decode(logits.argmax(-1))
```

But the output doesn't make sense:

```
['<extra_id_0> park park<extra_id_1> the<extra_id_2> park']
```

**I don't care for the loss, nor do I have labels in my setting. I just have text with masked tokens that I need to fill:**

```
my_masked_text = [
"The kid went to the [MASK]",
"The dog likes [MASK] and also [MASK]"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the in [docs for T5 (§ Inference)](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.29.1/model_doc/t5#inference)
there is an example of what you're looking for.

```py
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("t5-small")

input_ids = tokenizer("The <extra_id_0> walks in <extra_id_1> park", return_tensors="pt").input_ids

sequence_ids = model.generate(input_ids)
sequences = tokenizer.batch_decode(sequence_ids)
```

for the result that `sequences` is the following:

```py
['<pad><extra_id_0> park offers<extra_id_1> the<extra_id_2> park.</s>']
```

Where this to be interpreted as follows:

```py
'<pad>'                   # Marks beginning of output sequence 
'<extra_id_0> park offers'# <- model prediction for first blank
'<extra_id_1> the'        # <- model prediction for second blank
'<extra_id_2> park.</s>'  # ignore (there was no third blank)
```

So the model filled in the blanks as

"The ***park offers*** walks in ***the*** park"

---

For your examples, that means you'd do something like the following (haven't tested this, but it should work modulo some typo):

```py
my_masked_text = [
  "The kid went to the <extra_id_0>.",
  "The dog likes <extra_id_0> and also <extra_id_1>."
]

inputs = tokenizer(
  my_masked_text,    # tokenizer will encode each string in your list
  padding="longest", # need to pad if encoded strings are different of lengths
  return_tensors="pt", 
)

sequence_ids = model.generate(
  input_ids=inputs["input_ids"],
  attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"]
)
sequences = tokenizer.batch_decode(sequence_ids)
```

Then you should have a decoded predictions list `sequences` like the example above.